# Laravel and Monolog: Why do I get 'WARN' message on STDOUT with 'stderr' channel?

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, stderr, monolog, laravel-sail

I have a question about why Monolog on Laravel shows "WARN" message on STDOUT. How can I avoid it?

I'm running a new Laravel 10 project. I've created a RequestLogger middleware which executes the following line on every request, and I configured the $middleware attribute on Kernel.php file. Also I setted the 'stderr' channel on logging.php

```php
$log = [
   'URI' => $request->getUri(),
   'METHOD' => $request->getMethod(),
   'REQUEST_BODY' => $request->all()
];

Log::info('debug', $log);
```

If I browse a page:

```
   INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:9999].  

  Press Ctrl+C to stop the server

   WARN  local.INFO: array (.  

   WARN  'URI' => 'http://localhost:9999/',.
```

With the "stderr" channel appears on my console with "WARN"; but with "single" channel not. Why does WARN say?

I need to understand why that happens.

Comment: `With the "stderr" channel appears on my console with "WARN"; but with "single" channel not` <<<=== can you paste the complete error message? Also can you check the laravel.log? The warning should be in there as well.